# Parallel IO in R with rhdf5

Tags: r, parallel-processing, hdf5

I have a large amount of data in R data frames that I would like to write to an HDF5 file in parallel. In my initial experiments, the hdf5 file gets corrupted, presumably because parallel IO is not enabled in rhdf5. Is it possible to do parallel IO from R with rhdf5?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
library(parallel)
library(Rmpi)
library(rhdf5)

nwrites = 10000
db_name = 'testing_parallel_io.h5'

if(file.exists(db_name))unlink(db_name)
h5createFile(db_name)

write_data = function(index, db_name){

    suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(rhdf5))

    nr = 1000
    nc = 10
    df = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nr*nc),nr,nc))

    group_name = sprintf('group%05d',index)
    dataset_name = sprintf('%s/A',group_name)

    h5createGroup(db_name, group_name)
    h5write(df, db_name, dataset_name)

    return(0)
}

cl = makeCluster(detectCores(),type='MPI')
res = parSapply(cl, 1:nwrites, write_data, db_name)

stopCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

When I run this I get all sorts of errors from hdf5 like this:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 170 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to create dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #001: H5Dint.c line 431 in H5D_create_named(): unable to create and link to dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #002: H5L.c line 1640 in H5L_link_object(): unable to create new link to object
    major: Links
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: H5L.c line 1884 in H5L_create_real(): can't insert link
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Unable to insert object
  #004: H5Gtraverse.c line 905 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #005: H5Gtraverse.c line 799 in H5G_traverse_real(): component not found
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
```

Comment: It'd be nice to know what you're trying that isn't working, but my first thought is that if you are passing your connections to the worker nodes as variables, that won't work.  Connections will break down through the serialization/deserialization process of getting to the nodes.  I asked a similar question about database connections, but the answer can be applied to file connections as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541822/parlapply-on-sqlquery-from-rodbc . You simply need to define your connections on the workers before starting the routine.

Comment: I've added an example of what I'm doing. I'm not passing any file handles or connections they should get opened and closed after every write.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.  I've done a bunch of work with parallel but none with rhdf5.  From looking at the errors, I wonder if either the create group or write call in the function create locks on the db_name file so that only one process can use it at a time?  This would explain why a link can't be made.  A test you could do would be to initialize only one node, see if it works.  Then initialize two, and try again.  If one works and two doesn't, I'm probably on the right path, if neither work, then hopefully someone smarter than me comes along!

Comment: Thanks, it does work fine in serial. I am fairly certain these errors are because the rhdf5 package does not enable parallel io. I'm hoping someone smarter than me can fix that :)